# Return data from load state in jstree after refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I've got some problem with my jstree.

My code looks like:

```
<div id="jstree">
    <ul>
        <li>Folder 1
            <ul>
               <li id="child_1">Child 1</li>
               <li>Child 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Folder 2</li>
         <ul>
               <li id="child_1">Child 1</li>

               <li>Child 2</li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
$('#jstree').jstree({
                'core' : {'multiple' : false}, 
                'state' : { 'key' : 'jsCategoryTree', 'events' : 'activate_node.jstree'},
                'plugins' : ['state','cookies','ui','html_data'],
                'cookies' : { 'keep_selected':true},
                'themes': {'icons':false}
            });

           // return data selected option
            $('#jstree').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
                console.info(data.node.id);
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/764/

I have some tree and this object have some value. When i reload page previously selected returns correctly, but the data is not. How do I return data selected option after refresh page?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved my problem.

```
$('#jstree').jstree("get_selected", true);
```

this code return data from selected option after reload page :)